# Why aren't my Git variables being read in Docker Cloud Run

Tags: git, docker, express, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I have a Docker image running node14 with Express and Git. I set Git up in my Dockerfile like so:

```
FROM node:14
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install git -y
RUN git --version
RUN git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
RUN git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

running locally works fine, when I deploy and run on Google I get the following git error:

```
error: Command failed: git -C /usr/src/app/applications/ commit -m "First commit"

*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

git config --global user.email "you@example.com"

git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

Should I be doing something with my Dockerfile to make this work?

Comment: Cloud Run does not have a **user** environment. The concept of the home directory is not present. The file ~/.git/config does not exist or is in the wrong place, etc. Cloud Run is not persistent and you would need to run that command for each container start. I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but you make changes and then build the container, not the other way around.

Comment: @JohnHanley, are you saying that the issue is that git can’t find it’s config file? Is there a workaround for this where I can define a location where the file will be etc? I’m not too clear on the underlying architecture but my thinking is there must be some form of file system in place or node couldn’t function

Comment: I know Docker isn’t persistent, but I thought the idea was that an image would behave identically on startup regardless of where it was run. So confused why this isn’t happening

Comment: Cloud Run is not Docker. Cloud Run is an HTTP request/response system. Your concepts of an operating system, user namespace, etc do not exist in the same manner as a normal system. Yes, there is a **memory** based file system. Read these links: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/container-contract#filesystem and https://github.com/ahmetb/cloud-run-faq In summary, I still do not understand what you are trying to accomplish, but on first impression, I think you need to review the design of Cloud Run and what you can accomplish with it. **Great platform when used correctly.**

Comment: @JohnHanley it sounds like App Engine Flexible is a more suitable option for my needs then since it uses a compute engine underneath. I'll give it a try. Thanks.